# Neo4j MATCH query for connection between 3 nodes with different relations

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have below nodes and relationship between them.

```
A[name]    B[language]     C[Dependency]
John       Python          ML
Steven     Java            Tomcat
Jane       Scala           Spark
Roger      DB              SQL
Peter      Java            SQL
Rats       Scala           kafka
Ronny      Cobol           Tomcat


A-[:works_on]->B
B-[:works_with]->C
A-[:knows]->C
```

I am trying to get the graph which only shows those nodes which have all  connections like- A---B---C---A only distinct values no other independent connections. For this I am using below query:

```
MATCH (A)-[:works_on]->(B)-[:works_with]->(C) WHERE A.name = 'Peter' AND B.language = 'Java' Return A,B,C
```

Above query returning extra nodes along with desired nodes(Below Tomcat node is not require) How to get desired graph. like--

```
Desired graph-
Peter----Java---SQL---Peter
Actual graph-
Peter---Java---SQL & Tomcat---Peter
```

Answer (score 2):

Return the pattern that the MATCH found:

```
MATCH p=(a:A)-[r:works_on]->(b:B)-[s:works_with]->(c:C)<-[t:knows]-(a:A)
WHERE a.name = 'Peter' 
AND b.language = 'Java' 
Return p
```

By giving the same variable **a** to 2 nodes, you are adding the constraint that both nodes have to be the same for a given pattern.

For example, with the graph MOVIES:

```
MATCH p=(a:Person)-[r:ACTED_IN]-(b:Movie)-[s:DIRECTED]-(a:Person)
RETURN p
```

[image: movies query]

Comment: Still same output... extra nodes in a graph which have only one connection

Comment: add (C)<-[:knows]-(A) in the pattern. I edited the answer.

Comment: I added but still the same graph not desired one. The query is picking all B and C connections for JAVA.

Comment: We hadn't assigned variables in the path! now it should make sure that a has the same value in both sides of the path.

Comment: two r creating error.. "Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Cannot use the same relationship variable 'r' for multiple patterns"